# Way to keep Google from knowing the SIM card I am using on Android

Tags: privacy, android, google, smartphone, simcard

We see that the the details of the Telecom operator along with other details are available to Google for the SIM card that we are using on an Android Phone.

Is there any way that can be applied or implemented to keep Google from knowing the (exact) details of the SIM card operator for the SIM I am using?

Comment: Hi Abhi, could you give some more infos on the "info" that Google has access to? I think, have an idea what you mean, but would appreciate to see what you are going for, before I answer.

Comment: Don't use Google Play Services.

Comment: @Zonk I mean Phone Status And Identity related information along with the mobile operator info like which telecom company's SIM card you are actually using.

Comment: @Abhi in that case, I have a similar opinion like GdD's answer below. Your phone needs to know certain things and whether or not this is sent out to Google would need an assessment of the network traffic and source code. However, if you really would like not to have this done with your info, I think best is to buy an old Nokia like 3210 (as long as the network operators still run GSM).

Comment: @Zonk my aim is not to buy an old phone but to explore a method that can be applied against unwanted transmission of the user identity which is not only applicable to Google but other apps too......Hence I am trying to seek some guidance and opinion.

Comment: @Abhi Okay, well then first I would suggest you acknowledge that Google is able to get this information. After all, you are using a Google product and that seems part of the deal (the same applies for Apple, or Microsoft). However, how and to what extend they are "collecting" your ID is not clear to me. Nevertheless, for other apps there is a good way coming. With M, you can disable permissions of apps. So you will be able to prevent apps from reading your phone id and status etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for Android to make phone calls the OS has to be able to access the SIM details. It has to know what provider the sim belongs to in order to connect to that provider's towers. As google has written Android they can theoretically suck all the details they want off of it, and the only step you could take to prevent it would be to block your phone from accessing the internet. That would limit the usefulness of your phone dramatically of course.

If you're paranoid the option is there to write your own fork of android which would prevent it from sending data to google, which would be a very big project. It's possible someone has already done this.

Comment: sir could u plz provide some link or information related to the project.

Comment: I did not refer to a specific project @Abhi. I do not know of a release which blocks upload of data to google.

Comment: You can just block internet access to every google app with firewall and still have internet on other apps

Comment: Who's to say that there isn't a hidden channel independent of google apps @Freedo? If you care about it that much a firewall isn't a satisfactory solution.

Comment: I completely agree with you @GdD.......blocking internet access to google apps, or not using play store as stated by Natanael in the comment above are not the satisfactory solutions because there are great chances of a backdoor that send all of out unique identification details to google........which is why I am searching 4 a reliable and tested solution

Comment: @Freedo will it ensure that my mobile carrier information is not available to google whenever I change my SIM card?